# Fluent migrator throws timout exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, fluent-migrator

I using Fluent migrator 3.3.2, which throws error on one of databases:

```
The error was Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

I was looking for how to set timeout option and found this post https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator/discussions/1472

But `runner.RunnerContext` is marked as obsolete and in there is no comment what I have to use instead. If I try to use it like `runner.RunnerContext.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;` then have error:

```
Migration exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

Nothing found in google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set global timeout on dependency injection

```cs
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddFluentMigratorCore()
    .ConfigureRunner(rb => rb
        .AddSqlServer()
        //here
        .WithGlobalCommandTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120))
        .WithGlobalConnectionString(tenant.ConnectionString)
        .ScanIn(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly).For.Migrations())
    .Configure<RunnerOptions>(opt => { opt.Tags = new[] { tenant.Id }; })
    .AddLogging(lb => lb.AddFluentMigratorConsole())
    .AddLogging(lb => lb.AddSerilog())
    .BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: false);
```